# animations of multiple widths simultaneously, amounting to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to adjust the widths of two elements to expand to a wider area when a user closes a left panel. 
To do this I animate the left panel to right: 100%, and expand the first element to take over more area while keeping the second element with a fixed width (which also is an animation since now the whole div takes up more space so his percentage needs to change in order for it to take up the same pixel width)

The code is rather long so I won't post much of it here, stack overflow requires something so here's how I do the width animations:

```
  $('#centerWeb').animate({
                "width": "81.33333333%"
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: false
        });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpPG7/

I have several problems, the first, the animation isn't 'smooth', it's fidgety, I've heard or people saying that you can use the same timer queue for queuing animations but I couldn't find how (since I believed that small differences in percentages might cause this). 
Any ideas anyone could help with?

My second problem is that sometimes, like in the jsfiddle example, one of the center elements bounces down a row. In my complete web this happens when re-expanding the left area however in the JSfiddle example it happens when minimizing the left area.

In the JSFiddle: The left area when clicked removes it and expands the rest, and the red button when clicked expands the left area back.

My third and final problem, the animation of the left area, when expanding it back, doesn't occur at the same time as the expansion of the first center area (the actionList), it occurs once it's finished, despite being queue:false.

Comment: Im mobile, cant really code. I suggest to make s class in CSS that has '(-webkit-)transition: width 300ms linear; ' and u can use jQuery to set width withoutttt animation. I suspect jQuery does code-wise animation, setting values (100px -> 99px ->...-> 0px) which doesnt use GPU but CPU.

Comment: I'll give it a try, might help with making it more fluent.

Comment: I think that your approach is to complicated. There are some good plugins that achieve that. If you want to do it yourself, you should use float property. I'll try to give a fiddle to explain.

Comment: I gave everything float:left, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Ok, nevermind about `float`. Here is a possible approach that is fluent and need just a little code http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/Ft2cY/

Comment: Your JSFiddle looks very nice, and it might be a solution I will go for. If I'm right, the "test" area is only hidden and doesn't change at all, right?
The complexity of my problem is derived by the contextual relation between the two middle parts (which only one of them should expand). This whole middle area sometimes changes entirely to a different context ("MapView/DataView". I could split up the two middle area parts and expand only the leftest one - similarly to your solution but then they'd have to be in the same level of the leftest 'test' area.
I'll think about it, thanks for the input

Comment: yes, you are right. I have updated @EricG 's codePen and added the right part. The things I've done are : 1 rename rightContainer as centerContainer and create rightContainer. 2 : Set centerContainer a right margin of 30%. 3 Set the width of rightContainer at 30%. 4 : create a new stacking context for rightContainer, so it appears always on top.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hxidz

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I personally prefer [this codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ImznC):

```
#rightContainer{
    -webkit-transition: all linear 300ms;
    .. /* browser compatibility & remaining styles */
}
#rightContainer.shrink {
  left:20%;
}
```

and

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#rightContainer").toggleClass("shrink");
});
```

Which is imo clean & good practise.

Comment: I like your answer. But you are not the only one these to provide a solution with prefixes. Is it really a good practise ? I prefer Jquery instead of CSS. Maybe it's less efficient in term of CPU usage, but it's really easier to maintain.

Comment: cpu is not about efficiency, its about rendering quality. So use this with IE9+, then it wont be a problem I think. (having matching css)